# Searchkick async updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I started to use searchkick for connecting with elasticsearch, and I encountered a problem with index updating in background job. I did all by example in documentation, but searchkick tasks in sidekiq only accumulated and executed only after restarting sidekiq, and after execution, tasks collect again without execution. Below code.

Here my `searchkick.rb` initializer

```
Searchkick.client =
  Elasticsearch::Client.new(
    url: 'remote_ip:9200',
    retry_on_failure: true,
    transport_options: { request: { timeout: 250 } }
)

Searchkick.redis = ConnectionPool.new { Redis.new }
```

part of my model

```
after_commit  :searchkick_indexing

searchkick callbacks: :queue, index_name: :my_index_name

def search_data
  {
    title: title,
    description: description
  }
end

private

def searchkick_indexing
  Searchkick::ProcessQueueJob.perform_later(class_name: "model_name")
end
```

And, also, I added `searchkick` queue to `sidekiq.yml`.
How to performing searchkick job always without restarting sidekiq?
Thank in advance?

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps as listed here on [Searchkick Git Readme](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#queuing)---

Assuming you have Redis to store your jobs.

Add this to the model to indicate that Searchkick need to do the reindexing in the background asynchronously.

```
searchkick callbacks: :queue
```

And then in your sidekiq.yml, setup queue priority, shown below for sidekiq to prioritize the jobs -

```
###sample sidekiq.yml file
:concurrency: 5
:queues:
  - [searchkick, 2]
  - [mailers, 1]
  - [carrierwave, 1]
  - [default, 2]
staging:
  :concurrency: 10
production:
  :concurrency: 20
:logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
```

Restart the sidekiq with `bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml`

or setup Procfile for foreman to start multiple processes like -

```
#sample Procfile

web: bundle exec rails server
sidekiq: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
webpack: ./bin/webpack-dev-server
```

And with foreman, you can run all these commands in one way like -

`bundle exec foreman start`

This should work for you.